# How to reuse HTML snippets but change IDs of elements within them

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a browser-based drum machine, that allows the user to change the number of individual drum parts.

I have a chunk of HTML, that I wish to reuse for each drum part, which allows the user to change settings for that drum. As the user changes the amount of drum parts, a copy of this snippet should be appended to the page but with the ID for each element (and the contents of the h3 tag) reflecting the Drum Number it represents.

The HTML:

```
<div class="drumSettings" id="drum1Settings">
        <h3>Drum 1</h3>
        <div class="settings-item">
            <label for="drum1SectorCount">Sectors</label>
            <input type="number" name="drum1SectorCount" id="drum1SectorCount" value="16" min="2" max="32" onchange="redrawDrumLayer(this, 0)">
        </div>
        <div class="settings-item">
            <label for="drum1Sample">Sample</label>
            <select name="drum1Sample" id="drum1Sample" onchange="changeDrumSample(this, 0)">
                    <option value="samples/808 Kick.wav" selected="selected">808 Kick</option>      
                    <option value="samples/808 Snare.wav">808 Snare</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 Closed HiHat.wav">808 Closed HiHat</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 Open HiHat.wav">808 Open HiHat</option>  
                    <option value="samples/808 Clap.wav">808 Clap</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 Low Tom.wav">808 Low Tom</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 Mid Tom.wav">808 Mid Tom</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 High Tom.wav">808 High Tom</option>
                    <option value="samples/808 Cowbell.wav">808 Cowbell</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For example, the outer div for Drum 2 should have the ID 'drum2Settings' and the input element should have the ID 'drum2SectorCount'.

I already know one possible way of doing this: Writing the snippet over and over in HTML (up to the maximum possible number of drums allowed) and changing the display property to hide/show elements when needed—but this would result in a large HTML file (especially as I hope to add more settings for each drum in the future) and definitely goes against the Don't-Repeat-Yourself Methodology.

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery method that can take this first snippet and copy it while incrementing the numbers in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's appropriate here to use some template engine, like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/). Javascript implementation you may take from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janl/mustache.js/master/mustache.js). The manual for JS implementation is [here](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

The following is the working (at least in Firefox) example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="mustache.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Initiating default (1)
    var template = $('#template').html();
    Mustache.parse(template);
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {num: "1"});
    var target = $('#target');
    target.html(rendered);
    // Appending as required
    $('#select').change(function () {
        var n = $(this).val();
        target.empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            target.append(Mustache.render(template, {num: i})); 
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
    <div class="drumSettings" id="drum{{ num }}Settings">
        <h3>Drum {{ num }} </h3>
        <div class="settings-item">
            <label for="drum{{ num }}SectorCount">Sectors</label>
            <input type="number" name="drum{{ num }}SectorCount" id="drum{{ num }}SectorCount" value="16" min="2" max="32" onchange="redrawDrumLayer(this, 0)">
        </div>
        <div class="settings-item">
            <label for="drum{{ num }}Sample">Sample</label>
            <select name="drum{{ num }}Sample" id="drum{{ num }}Sample" onchange="changeDrumSample(this, 0)">
                <option value="samples/808 Kick.wav" selected="selected">808 Kick</option>      
                <option value="samples/808 Snare.wav">808 Snare</option>
                <option value="samples/808 Closed HiHat.wav">808 Closed HiHat</option>
                <option value="samples/808 Open HiHat.wav">808 Open HiHat</option>  
                <option value="samples/808 Clap.wav">808 Clap</option>
                <option value="samples/808 Low Tom.wav">808 Low Tom</option>
                <option value="samples/808 Mid Tom.wav">808 Mid Tom</option>
                <option value="samples/808 High Tom.wav">808 High Tom</option>
                <option value="samples/808 Cowbell.wav">808 Cowbell</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Choose drums amount <select id="select" name="drums">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example the template is hidden (display: none), but you also may load it from an external file by AJAXing your web server (if you have one accessible - you have an example of such request in the Mustache manual).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You. This does exactly what I need. I'll look at making an AJAX request to tidy up my HTML

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into .clone in jquery - you can clone the html and make edits to it before reinserting it into the page
http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery for this, though it might be easier to set up the event watching, and to get the DOM elements with it.

```
//cache these externally, so you can increment the count variable and don't have to declare the other two every time
var count = 1;
var htmlPart1 = '<div class="drumSettings" id="drum1Settings"><h3>Drum ';
var htmlPart3 = '</h3>...' //the rest of the HTML snippet here.
var addDrum = function(){
    //build the html string you want to input
    count++;
    var htmlStr = htmlPart1 + count + htmlPart3;

    //get the DOM object you want to append the html to, append it.
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + htmlStr;
};

//this triggers the function, it can be any event you want.
someElement.onclick = addDrum;
```

For increased performance (and learning!) you can change the list of strings to an array of strings and join them.

Comment: I get the idea here, but I was looking to change the IDs as well. I assume I could just break each string anywhere I want to add the count variable. So htmlPart1 (or the first item in the array) would be `'<div class="drumSettings" id="drum'` and the next item after that would be `'Settings"><h3>Drum '`

Comment: @user3280865 Yep, you got it. You can break the string up as many times as you want, adding dynamic content as you go.